# Webpack babel-loader need babel.config.js or not?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I have a webpack setting like below

```
test: /\.m?js$/,
exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
use: {
  loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory',
  options: {
    presets: [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      '@babel/react', // Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.
    ],
    plugins: [
      [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators',
        {
          legacy: true,
        },
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        {
          loose: true,
        },
      ],
    ],
  },
},
```

So do i still need add a file `babel.config.js` or `.babelrc` to double the config again?

if i use vscode, do i need this file `babel.config.js` for some plugin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No that is redundant. I see you are using the example in `babel-loader` docs. I'd recommend to use the [example](https://babeljs.io/setup#installation) in official babel docs (click on webpack). That keeps your webpack config simple and allows over easy overrides of babel in folders by placing a `.babelrc` in directories where'd you like different settings.

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"            
        "@babel/preset-react",
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        {
            "loose: true
        }
    ]
}
```

**Your webpack config file**

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"
        }
    ]
}
```

Considering that error: make sure you've at least installed `@babel/preset-react` and `@babel/preset-env`, `@babel/core` and `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`! You might be using babel 6 plugins. Could you share your `package.json`?

Comment: when using a babel.config.js as well as specifying options in loaders, would it merge both or ignore the babel.config.js ?

Comment: @gaurav5430, it seems like it merge options both from `babel.config.json` and `options` from the loaders section of the `webpack.config.js`

Comment: @JamesBond How did you check that? And another question, who wins the override in case of duplicates/conflicts?